# Matrix representation when dimension is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading Friedberg's Linear Algebra. In section 2.2 the authors define the matrix representation of a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces. I understand the definition, except in the special cases where $\dim(V)=0$ or $\dim(W)=0$, i.e. $\emptyset$ is the ordered basis for $V$ or $W$. What is the matrix representation in these cases?

It seems like the book discards these cases, as if an ordered basis had to be nonempty.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from defining the zero-dimension matrices ?

Comment: Pathological case. Empty mapping.

Comment: Can someone please delete my answer, I made a hige mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It would have to be an empty matrix $()$ of size $0 \times 0$. If you identify $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with the space of functions from $\{1,\ldots,n\}\times \{1,\ldots,p\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then the empty matrix would correspond to the empty function (the only function from $\emptyset$ to $\mathbb{R}$).